# Detect Android pinch to zoom innerWidth with JavaScript/Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, hammer.js, jquery-events

I want to know the innerWith/viewport width of the pinch to zoom when it's zoomed.

If it's below 500 px I want to change the image with:

```
$("img#ad").attr("src", "http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/1/L/mmy4jT8s/jsFiddle3.png");
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("log"));

hammer.ontransformstart = function(ev) {
    var pziW = "test"; // Declare here the innerWidth of the pinch to zoom
    if (pziW < 500) {
        $("img#ad").attr("src", "http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/1/L/mmy4jT8s/jsFiddle3.png");
    }
};
hammer.ontransform = function(ev) {
    var pziW = "test"; // Declare here the innerWidth of the pinch to zoom
    if (pziW < 500) {
        $("img#ad").attr("src", "http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/1/L/mmy4jT8s/jsFiddle3.png");
    }
};
hammer.ontransformend = function(ev) {
    var pziW = "test"; // Declare here the innerWidth of the pinch to zoom
    if (pziW < 500) {
        $("img#ad").attr("src", "http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/1/L/mmy4jT8s/jsFiddle3.png");
    }
};
```

But I don't know how to declare the innerWidth of the pinch to zoom.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nLvu6/

Somebody has an answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is not innerWidth that you would like to detect.

Take a look at the ev variable passed to the hammer functions:

```
distance: 0
distanceX: 0
distanceY: 0
originalEvent: TouchEvent
position: Object
rotation: 124.85234015769826
scale: 2.0725083746457824
touches: Array[0]
type: "transformend"
__proto__: Object
```

`scale: 2.0725083746457824` is the one we want. If the scale is above or below a certain threshold, then perform your image replacement function.

I have forked your JSFiddle. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BFBrU/14/

[image: Before pinch][image: After pinch]

Comment: I've tried to calculate the innerWidth with: pziW = $(window).innerWidth() / 2 * ev.scale; but It returns 0 the whole time, is there something wrong with my calculation? Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLvu6/20/

Comment: Also on an other forum someone suggested this calculation: on page start: set viewport-width variable to initial width ontransformstart: zoom variable = ev.scale (it'll be 1.0) ontransform: calculate zoom delta (zoom variable -= ev.scale) viewport-width += viewport width * zoom delta zoom variable = ev.scale How can I put this in a calculation? I've tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/nLvu6/22/ and with "hammer.bind": http://jsfiddle.net/nLvu6/21/